# Docker Postgres database not running or accessible

Tags: docker

Below is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /workspace
COPY . .
COPY /prisma ./prisma/
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3333
EXPOSE 9229

CMD [  "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

And my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  todoapp-api:
    container_name: todoapp-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3333:3333

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.5
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=myuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

volumes:
  postgres:

networks:
  nestjs-crud:
```

And my `.env:`

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://myuser:mypassword@192.168.1.1/mydb?schema=public"
```

After struggling with making the database run and be accessible, I found out that one possible solution was to change the `DATABASE_URL`. As you can see, I am writing my IP Address there to get it to run and this works for me. However, when I replace `192.168.1.1` with the name of the service: `postgres`, it stops working and I get the error:
`Can't reach database server at postgres:5432`

Writing the IP address is not ideal of course. However, if I don't write the IP address then the database server just doesn't work.

Comment: Configure a docker image has nothing to do with programming. So please ask on another site please!

Comment: Are you encountering this error during the image build, or only when running the image?  (It'd be unusual, but does `npm install` need to contact the database?)  You have a `networks:` block at the very end of the file, but nowhere else; is that in fact the only `networks:` block?  (If so, the `nextjs-crud` network is unused and you can delete that block.)

Answer (score -1):

I think you may need to atributte networks in the containers specs. You already defined what networks you have in the YAML but they need to be inserted in container's spec like

```
todoapp-api:
container_name: todoapp-api
networks:
- nestjs-crud
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
ports:
  - 3333:3333
networks:
  nestjs-crud:
    internal: true
```

My recomendation is to create one network for the db and other for the API, then assing the network db for the db, and both in the API, thus, the API can acess db network. Than, you can acess the db by the host nestjs-crud.postgres

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this out but still getting the same error. The only way I can access the database is if I use IP Address sadly.

Comment: Try to use the internal parameter. I will edit my anwser so you can see better how to use.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

To bounce back, on the point of the comment above, the two services are not in the same network, which is why you have the concern. To solve this problem, it will be necessary to put the services in the same network by putting the mention:

```
networks:
- nestjs-crud
```

and `depends_on` in todoapp-api

in the todoapp-api and postgres service, this becomes:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  todoapp-api:
    container_name: todoapp-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    networks:
      - nestjs-crud
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.5
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=myuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      - nestjs-crud

volumes:
  postgres:

networks:
  nestjs-crud:
```

And add in .env database service name.

Comment: Both containers are in a network named `default` already.  The `nextjs-crud` network is unused and could be deleted.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes this setup.